# C# Return var from function

Tags: c#, function, return, var

I want to use modular programming in C#. I tried to create a method with a Linq query. As far as I know I need to store the Linq query in a variable in order to execute it. I created a class and method named `SearchStudent()`, but I do not know how to return the Linq query. What should I do?

```
public var SearchStudent(string ogrenci_id)
{
    var query =
         from d in context.ogrencis
         where d.ogrenci_id ==Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci_id)
         select new
         {
             d.ogrenci_adi,
             d.ogrenci_soyadi
         };

    return query;
}
```

Comment: over your mouse on var keyword and it should tell what type it's using and use that as a return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type is an `IEnumerable<T>` where the `T` is an anonyous type. You can't statically define an anonymous type, since it's anonymous.

There are two solutions:

1. Use `IEnumerable` as return type of the method:

   ```
   public IEnumerable SearchStudent(string o)
   ```
2. Define the class yourself

   ```
   public class Result
   {
       public int Adi { get; set; }

       public int Soy { get; set; }
   }

   public IEnumerable<Result> SearchStudent(string o)
   {
       return
           from d in context.ogrencis
           where d.ogrenci_id    
           select new Result
           {
               Adi = d.ogrenci_adi,
               Soy = d.ogrenci_soyadi
           };
   }
   ```

Comment: Please **never** use the first solution. Don't return an `IEnumerable`, only return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @user1908061: You can't say "never", because sometimes you don't need static typing at all (binding in WPF and Win Forms for instance) and in that case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Even then I can say **never**, because in that case it's still better to use a proper type. It does not harm, and you clearly see what type this method is intended to return. It is called `defensive programming`, and when you look months later at your code you'll be thankful for using the typed version.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> when i type it,
The type or namespace T could not be Found

Comment: @Unnamed: You can't do that. You have to specify what `T` is. You can't specify what `T` is because it's anonymous. It's a [horse with no name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Horse_with_No_Name), so you can't type it's name when you need it. That's why it's called an *anonymous* type.

Comment: First Solution It doesn't work

Comment: @Unnamed: It *can* be made to work, but it's the *wrong* solution. **Do not do it**.

Comment: Also,second does not work

Comment: @Unnamed I can assure you it does work. Of course you can't just copy and paste the code above, but the solution provided does work. I'm sorry, but perhaps you should get a book and read the pure basics of C# first?

Comment: @Unnamed: Second works (with a small necessary fix); you're just not doing it right.

Comment: Of course i know C# programming.I will tell you step by step what i did.

Comment: @user1908061: I stand corrected. OP seems to have very little experience. In that case, the first solution is indeed a bad solution.

Comment: @Steven It still is **always** a bad solution.

Comment: @user1908061: Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: for me is right working. tnx for u...............

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid that's not possible as `var` is only valid within method scope. Return type needs to be a explicit type.

A solution would be creating a class for storing query result instead of using anonymous types.

Answer (score 4):

For the love of all the little kittens in this world, would you please just create a concrete type? Yes, it's boilerplate, but it's simple. It will make your solution infinitely more maintainable than passing around sequences of anonymous types (yes, that's an option; **do not do it**).

```
class QueryResult {
    public int Orgrenci_adi { get; private set; }
    public int Orgrenci_soyadi { get; private set; }

    public QueryResult(int orgrenci_adi, int orgrenci_soyadi) {
        this.Orgrenci_adi = orgrenci_adi;
        this.Orgrenci_soyadi = orgrenci_soyadi;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<QueryResult> SearchStudent(string ogrenci_id) {
    return
        from d in context.ogrencis
        where d.ogrenci_id == Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci_id)
        select new QueryResult(d.ogrenci_adi, d.ogrenci_soyadi);
}
```

You simply can not use `var` as a return type. `var` says to the compiler, look, you do your thing and *you* figure out what the type is. Can you imagine the complexity in implementing that for *return types* in the compiler? Imagine an arbitrarily long chain of nested methods all calling each all with return type `var`. The compiler would have to do a lot of work to resolve what the types are. There are features *way* more worthwhile than that to implement.

Comment: Do note that depending on the used query technology, the statement `select new QueryResult(d.ogrenci_adi, d.ogrenci_soyadi)` might not work (because for some bullshit reason, even version 6 of f*cking Entity Framework only supports default constructors). With EF, you'll need to write `new QueryResult { X = x, Y = y }`.

Answer (score 1):

They `var` keyword will be replaced with the actual type while compiling, `var` itself is no type so you can't return it.

In your case you're doing a `projection`, and you get an `anonymous type`. You can't return `anonymous types` from a method. Your only option is to create a class and return that.

```
class MyClass { .. }

var query =
     from d in context.ogrencis
     where d.ogrenci_id ==Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci_id)
     select MyClass new
     {
         d.ogrenci_adi,
         d.ogrenci_soyadi
     };

    return query;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic, but i'm not sure it's a good idea.

```
public dynamic SearchStudent(string ogrenci_id)
{
  var query =
     from d in context.ogrencis
     where d.ogrenci_id ==Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci_id)
     select new
     {
         d.ogrenci_adi,
         d.ogrenci_soyadi
     };

    return query;

}
```

Comment: It is **not** a good idea to use `dynamic` in this case. He should create a type for it, or use `Tuple`.

Comment: it doesnt work because i cannot receive returning content in main.

Comment: @Unnamed I tried with a List of string, and it works.

Comment: how could you do it ?

Comment: var myObj = SearchStudent("AnId");

Comment: I understand but you need to publish SearchStudent() method inside.

Answer (score 0):

in your case , u have to use following code

```
public SearchStudent(string ogrenci_id)
{
  var query =
     from d in context.ogrencis
     where d.ogrenci_id ==Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci_id)
     select new
     {
         d.ogrenci_adi,
         d.ogrenci_soyadi
     };

    return query;
}
```

it will work.

Comment: This won't even compile. You're omitting the return type of your method.

Comment: Really,it can return syntax error

Comment: its work in javascript.

Comment: this is not javascript,this is c#